# Image Style in Views Module Is Not Working Properly?

Tags: views, media

Image style in views was working fine, but then I don't know what happened. Please see this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PHTh356WgfM&feature=youtu.be.  I have several days tried to fix this problem but I can't figured out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

This is what I want, I want views to resize an image to 300px by 300px using the image style I was able to accomplished. Here is my website: carlosgandara.com

Comment: Does this only happen in Views preview or in the actual view also?

Comment: It doesn't work either in the actual page.

Comment: Can you see a resized image when viewing a single node?